# Angular ui-router on wordpress page

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, angular-ui-router

I'm developing on `http://localhost:3000/af2015/web/` (the extra directories will not be present on the production site) and using wordpress. My Angular app is on the `/recommendations` page, which includes this template:

```
<div ng-app="af2015App">
    <div ng-controller="MapCtrl as vm">
        <map center="[52.374, 4.899]" zoom="12">
        </map>
    </div>

    <section>
        <div ui-view>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The `ui-view` template is not being loaded, nor the controller being initialised. This is my config function, and I have tried all sorts of permutations of `<base href="/af2015/web" />` tag. There are no errors in my console.

```
angular.module('af2015App')
    .config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider.state('list', {
            //url: '/:alpha/:beta/:gamma',
            url: '/recommendations',
            template: '<h2>List</h2>',
            controller: "ListController",
            controllerAs: 'list'
        });
    });
```

Comment: States in URL when using ui-router are added/changed after # symbol so you should try to remove 'af2015/web/' from your url property

Comment: @shershen I'm using html5 urls, not least as wordpress is creating the links up to the `/recommendations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try enough permutations. This one worked:

```
<base href="/af2015/web/recommendations/" />
```

And then

```
$stateProvider.state('list', {
    url: '/',
```